# How to create initial influxdb2 token from CLI?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, influxdb

I just migrated my influxdb 1.8 to influxdb 2.7 on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS server. I did it from package repo.

Migration went fine, but new CLI client asks token for everything.

I saw `influx auth create` command is there to do so but it also requests a valid token.

Migration script, part of the package, made me only a username and a password but token.

Finally I could login with my username and password via the web UI and create a new token as a workaround but it must not be mandatory I think. (BTW even an "All Access API token" can be used to create backups)